# I'm looking for drone simulator

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi. I'm Takeru Kobayashi, a staff of CLUE, Inc. in Japan.
URL: https://corp.t-clue.com/
CLUE is an engineering company of drone, and looking for simulator for drone.

I find this simulator so I want to know what is/isn't able to do with it.
Can I get any answers of following 12 questions below?
Thank you for reading!

Q.01
What kind of data can be inputed to the simulator?
For example, stick angle of remote controller, aircraft's attitude,
waypoint flight and so on.

Q.02
What kind of data can be output from the simulator?
And what kind of data format is it?
For example, aircraft's attitude, rotor output, flight path,
low-level signal between remote controller and flight controller
and so on.

Q.03
How detailed control can it accept?
For example, latitude / longitude resolution of waypoints,
unit of controller stick angle, time resolution of aircraft's attitude
and so on.

Q.04
Can its signal be sent to a real aircraft?
We want to real drones (Parrot, DJI, ...) to fly with same conditions used in simulator.

Q.05
Does it collaborate with other software?
For example, controllable by ROS or V-rep, programmable by standard language (Python, C++, ...)
and so on.

Q.06
Does it render images from simulated camera?
If so, how high is its quality? Wireframe, simple solid body or textured object?
Environment lighting and landscape can be simulated?

Q.07
What kind of sensor can be simulated?
I guess it simulates GPS, IMU (acceleration and gyro) and compass.
How about other sensors? For example, LIDAR, thermal sensor, sonar ranging and so on.

Q.08
Can the the simulator run multiple aircrafts at same time?

Q.09
Is that possible to simulate environmental conditions?
For example, wind, rain, dynamic environment objects and so on.

Q.10
Can it simulate drone's breakdown?

Q.11
Can it output low-level signal between remote controller and flight controller?

Q.12
Is there any plugin or customization of the simulator?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15520/i%27m-looking-for-drone-simulator/) by [Takeru](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3085/takeru/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Most of your questions revolve around flexibility, compatibility, and customization. Gazebo uses plugins to accept custom inputs, output custom data, and perform custom control in simulation. There are tutorials about this located at gazebosim.org/tutorials.

There is a [ROS interface to Gazebo](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_pkgs).

Gazebo does simulate camera data by rendering OpenGL scenese. Quality depends on the meshes and materials that are used in the scene.

There are many sensors available in gazebo, including but not limited to 2d & 3d cameras, LIDAR, Sonar, IMU, and GPS.

Yes, gazebo can run multiple aircrafts at the same time.

Gazebo can simulate wind and dynamic objects.

A plugin that you write could simulate drone breakdown.

A plugin that you write could output low-level signals.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Takeru](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3085/takeru/) on 2017-03-06**:
Dear nkoenig,

Thank you for your answers!
They help me to select the best simulator meets my purposes.

I'm new to Gazebo and very interested in it.
Thank you,